# How to verify an object instance? instanceof and ....prototype.isPrototypeOf(...) are not reliable

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype, instance, instanceof

I work with Node.js.

Please read this code:

`Project/Application/application.js`:

```
const onecolor = require("onecolor");
const library = require("../Library/library.js");

library.check(new onecolor.RGB(0, 0, 0));
```

`Project/Library/library.js`:

```
const onecolor = require("onecolor");

module.exports.check = function(object) {
    console.log(`Library-made object: ${
            onecolor.RGB.prototype.isPrototypeOf(
            new onecolor.RGB(0, 0, 0))}`);
    console.log(`Application-made object: ${
            onecolor.RGB.prototype.isPrototypeOf(
            object)}`);
};
```

Both directories have a `node_modules` directory with the `onecolor` module installed.

I'm running `node application.js` from within the `Project/Application` directory.

The output shows that `....prototype.isPrototypeOf(...)` is not a reliable method for verifying whether an object is of the correct "class" *when* the script file for building the objects is not the same (different `node_modules` directories):

```
Library-made object: true
Application-made object: false
```

Why is this? And how to workaround this? That is, what's a reliable method for verifying whether an object is a specific kind of instance?

Comment: There are two separate instances of the constructor and prototype objects, one for each imported copy of the "onecolor" code.

Comment: So Node.js internally doesn't really `require` something twice (reading the file) when the installation directory is one and the same?

Comment: Yes, it would not, but you're having two `onecolor` directories

Comment: Btw, why not use `instanceof …` instead of `….prototype.isPrototypeOf`? (of course, makes no differences to the problem here)

Comment: @Bergi: This is just for reasons of personal short-time history. *Doesn't the problem have to be one that was already encountered very often?*

Comment: You're right, it is encountered by others as well (though it doesn't manifest as a *problem* very often). Closing as a duplicate :-)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help!